# MYSQL - Insert en una tabla dependiendo de una condición (si existe el id no se añade, si no existe sí)

Tags: mysql, python, base-de-datos, insert

tengo una duda ya que quiero hacer una consulta sobre una base de datos. Lo que tengo se corresponde con un script de python linkeado con mysql:

```
def datos(name, id, result):
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resultados (name VARCHAR (200), Result VARCHAR(45), ID INT")
    sql = ("INSERT INTO resultados (name, Result, ID) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
    data = (name, id, result)
    mycursor.execute(sql, data)
```

La función 'datos' me va a devolver distintos resultados cada vez que se ejecute, por ejemplo:

```
"Juan", "1", "hombre"
"Pedro", "2", "hombre"
```

Estos datos se van guardando en una base de datos cada vez que se ejecute el script. Hasta ahí funciona bien, pero cuando lo ejecuto una 2a vez, aunque los valores sean los mismos, también se guardan en la base de datos, y eso es lo que no quiero; que si se repite el id, no se guarde. Es decir, que si Pedro cambia su id (que eso depende de otra función que no viene al caso), sí se vuelva a guardar en la base de datos.

Según he visto en foros, la solución sería añadir algo parecido a lo siguiente

```
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE ID )
```

Pero probando con varias sentencias similares, no consigo lo que quiero, saltan errores.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'W
```

Si alguien me ayuda sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque creas la tabla en cada pasada??? con que sentido??? y luedo de ello, lo que leiste es lo correcto, deberias agregar los datos si no existen, y para eso tenes que hacer una consulta que se fijen si exsiten o no.

Comment: que tal si usas un upsert

Comment: Que quiere decir no me sale? da un error? que fue lo que intentaste? no podemos corregir lo que intentaste, si no lo mostras

Comment: que no funciona, he probado varias sentencias similares a la que he escrito arriba pero saltan errores, ahora mismo tengo el código que he puesto. Sólo me falta poner esa comprobación para que no inserte si se repite el id

Comment: y cual es el error? podemor verlos, por lo pronto vemos una consulta y un enunciado

Comment: porque no, lo intentas cambiandolo con un procedimiento almacenado?

Answer (score 0):

**`key update` se usa en mysql inserta pero si existe otro registro con el mismo id solo lo actualiza**

```
INSERT INTO resultados (`id`, `name`, `result`)  
VALUES (4, 'jorge', 'ssss')   
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='jorge', result='ssss';
```